# Space-time translations and Propagator

Tags: quantum-field-theory, poincare-symmetry, propagator

Let us assume to have the following scalar field theory
$$
    {\cal A}=\int d^4x\left[\frac{1}{2}(\partial\phi)^2-\frac{\lambda}{4}\phi^4\right]
$$
where I used a quartic potential to fix the ideas. Also, let us suppose we know the exact propagator $G(x,0)=\langle T\phi(x)\phi(0)\rangle$ in a closed form and I would like to compute $G(x,y)$. What would translation operator be to accomplish the task?

I would like to know the explicit form if any. This is a kind of general mathematical problem. If you are able to solve an ordinary differential equation like $\ddot x+\Omega(t) x=0$ you will easily get the Green function $G(t,0)$ but how to get $G(t,t')$?

Answer (score 0):

Translation invariance implies that the propagator only depends on the difference of coordinates,
$$G(x,y) = F(x-y) \, ,$$
for some function $F(r)$. Choosing $y=0$ yields
$$G(x,0) = F(x) \, ,$$
and
$$G(x,y) = G(x-y,0) \, .$$

Tada!

Comment: I feel, like you are expecting some more complicated answer. Please tell me if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Apply this to the following Green function $\ddot G(t,t')+\Omega(t) G(t,t')=\delta(t-t')$.

Comment: This only works when $d\Omega/dt = 0$. If not your system is not time-translation invariant and $G(t,t')$ depends on both times separately. If $\Omega(t) = \Omega$, the greens function obeys $G''(t,0) + \Omega G(t,0) = \delta(t)$.

Comment: That's my point. How can I get back from $G(t,0)$ to $G(t,t')$? Of course, your answer is not really an answer but rather a comment of a well-known fact.

Comment: If you need more information on why this is so, I am happy to extend my question.

Comment: But, if $\Omega$ depends on $t$, you simply can't know $G(t,t')$ from $G(t,0)$. If you look only at $G(t,0)$ you are missing half of the information contained in $G(t,t')$.

Comment: Yes, I would like to know if some technique is known about this, if the physics coming our from $G(t,0)$ is enough without knowing $G(t,t')$ and so on. It is also possible that no answer is known and this will be a legal answer too.

Comment: Then it depends highly on the particular choice of $\Omega(t)$ and the relation of $t$ and $t'$ to it's dimension-full parameters. Maybe you can find a parameter region where time-translation invariance is approximately restored. I don't know of any techniques which might help you there, sorry.

Comment: Steven, thanks anyway. I know this is not a very simple problem and probably not much is known unless some particular forms of $\Omega(t)$ are known. But I hope someone else could help on this.

Comment: You could list the question on the mathematics exchange.  Once you violate energy conversation it's no longer physics in my opinion.